# Cyclone Slider short code not working

Tags: php, wordpress

i installed cyclone slider 1.3.4 plugin in wordpress site i followed each step and instruction from

Here

### http://www.codefleet.net/cyclone-slider/

but when i include short code which is `[cycloneslider id="my-slider"]`  enter code hereto my header page this error comes...

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING), expecting ']' in C:\wamp\www\store-to-ship
```

Please any one who can help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried different ways and finally solved problem here by simply adding this

`<?php echo do_shortcode("[cycloneslider id='1']");?>`

i am new in WordPress so i was confused..:)